# Set the value of a nested dict of unknown depth?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, dictionary

So I have a list which acts as a 'map' of sorts, and a dict which is pulled from a JSON file.

For this example, lets say they look like this:

```
L = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']

D = {
    "One": {
        "Two": {
            "Three": {
                "Four": "String"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need a function for my game.

I will be passing it two things: `L` and a `Object`.

Note that `L` just leads to `"Three"` so thats what I want to replace. Though, I could be replacing `"Four"` or any other element at an unknown debth.

What I'm replacing could be a `string`, `list`, or `dict`, and I could be replacing it with any other object, including `None`, or a `bool`.

The structure of `D` needs to remain intact, besides the value being replaced.

Comment: So, what is an example of the result?

Comment: This is not a Duplicate. I want to `set` the value, not check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will take a list of strings as a path and an object to replace the located value with, operating on a global variable `nested_dicts`. If you want to adhere to a functional paradigm, you might want to rewrite it accordingly.

```
def replace (path, replacement):
    pointer = nested_dicts
    try:
        for key in path[:-1]:
            pointer = pointer[key]
    except KeyError:
        return False
    pointer[path[-1]] = replacement
    return True
```

Comment: The result is just final value from path and it's new value, the rest of `D` needs to remain intact.

Comment: I don't understand your statement "The result is just final value from path and it's new value". Is that what you think my code does, or what you want it to do? What it does is replace the specified value and leave the rest intact.

Comment: Sorry, I was checking the result of `pointer`, I didn't know it replaced the original.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works (`path` is `L`, `o` is the replacement):

```
L = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']

D = {
    "One": {
        "Two": {
            "Three": {
                "Four": "String"
            }
        }
    }
}

def replace(path, o):
    cur = D
    for k in path[:-1]:
        cur = cur[k]
    cur[path[-1]] = o

replace(L, {'msg': 'good'})
print(D)
```

Comment: This is the same as the earlier answer, which doesn't return the value I'm looking for.

Comment: well I actually tried and it did work. Posting the full code

Comment: ..Ohh.. How does it set the value to `D`? I was checking `cur`

Comment: `cur = D` :D. Of course you can pass it in as a param as well